# Pygame не всегда срабатывает событие щелчка лкм

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Простой алгоритм, который при нажатии лкм выводит в консоль номер ячейки по которой кликнул, но работает как то странно. Иногда работает корректно, а иногда приходится кликать по несколько раз, что бы напечатал номер ячейки.
Почему так происходит? Как исправить?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygame

pygame.init() # ицициализирует все импортированные модули Pygame
size = (800, 600) # размер игрового окна
display = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
name_display = pygame.display.set_caption("MyGame") # название окна
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
display.fill((255, 255, 255))

pygame.display.update()

def run_game():
    clock.tick(30)
    game = True
    while game:
        mouse_cell()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

def lines():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (225, 0, 0), (25, 15, 50, 50), 3)
    pygame.draw.line(display, (0, 0, 0), [0, 100], [552, 100], 4)
    pygame.draw.line(display, (0, 0, 0), [550, 100], [550, 600], 4)

    pygame.draw.line(display, (77, 77, 77), (25, 125), (525, 125), (2)) #по x
    pygame.draw.line(display, (77, 77, 77), (25, 125), (25, 575), (2)) #по y

    x = 175
    while x < 600:
        pygame.draw.line(display, (77, 77, 77), [25, x], [525, x], 2)
        x += 50
    y = 75
    while y < 575:
        pygame.draw.line(display, (77, 77, 77), [y, 125], [y, 575], 2)
        y += 50

    pygame.display.update()


def mouse_cell():
    start_x = 25
    start_y = 125
    step = 50
    side = 50
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  # координаты щелчка мыши
            mouse_p = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            mouse_p = list(mouse_p)
            mouse_x = mouse_p[0]
            mouse_y = mouse_p[1]
            for y in range(0, 9):
                for x in range(0, 10):
                    cell_x = start_x + x * step
                    cell_y = start_y + y * step
                    if cell_x <= mouse_x <= cell_x + side and cell_y <= mouse_y <= cell_y + side:
                        print('start ' + str(y * 10 + x))


lines()
run_game()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это из-за того, что вы обрабатываете события в двух разных циклах. Проще всего починить, если перенести обработку всех событий в один цикл:

```
import pygame

pygame.init() # ицициализирует все импортированные модули Pygame
size = (800, 600) # размер игрового окна
display = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
name_display = pygame.display.set_caption("MyGame") # название окна
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
display.fill((255, 255, 255))

pygame.display.update()

def run_game():
    clock.tick(30)
    game = True
    while game:
        mouse_cell()
#        for event in pygame.event.get():
# Цикл обработки событий должен быть один!!!

def lines():
    pygame.draw.rect(display, (225, 0, 0), (25, 15, 50, 50), 3)
    pygame.draw.line(display, (0, 0, 0), [0, 100], [552, 100], 4)
    pygame.draw.line(display, (0, 0, 0), [550, 100], [550, 600], 4)

    pygame.draw.line(display, (77, 77, 77), (25, 125), (525, 125), (2)) #по x
    pygame.draw.line(display, (77, 77, 77), (25, 125), (25, 575), (2)) #по y

    x = 175
    while x < 600:
        pygame.draw.line(display, (77, 77, 77), [25, x], [525, x], 2)
        x += 50
    y = 75
    while y < 575:
        pygame.draw.line(display, (77, 77, 77), [y, 125], [y, 575], 2)
        y += 50

    pygame.display.update()


def mouse_cell():
    start_x = 25
    start_y = 125
    step = 50
    side = 50
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  # координаты щелчка мыши
            mouse_p = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            mouse_p = list(mouse_p)
            mouse_x = mouse_p[0]
            mouse_y = mouse_p[1]
            for y in range(0, 9):
                for x in range(0, 10):
                    cell_x = start_x + x * step
                    cell_y = start_y + y * step
                    if cell_x <= mouse_x <= cell_x + side and cell_y <= mouse_y <= cell_y + side:
                        print('start ' + str(y * 10 + x))

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

lines()
run_game()
```

У вас просто получается, что один цикл съедает все имеющиеся события, но реагирует только на команду выхода, а остальные события просто пропадают. А другой цикл наоборот - реагирует на мышь, но не реагирует на всё остальное. И они вот так по очереди работают, теряя то одни события, то другие.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло